# What does uMsg parameter mean in the definition of CALLBACK DialogProc()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dialog, callback, modal-dialog

The MSDN link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

explains about the **DialogProc callback function**.

Here I don't see any explanation given about the 2nd parameter (UINT uMsg) in the following signature::

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(   
  __in  HWND hwndDlg,   
  __in  UINT uMsg,   
  __in  WPARAM wParam,   
  __in  LPARAM lParam   
);
```

Can anyone kindly explain what does this 2nd parameter (UINT uMsg) mean. Some detailed explanation (Why we need this uMsg parameter, what is its usage how is it used etc...)  on this will be really appreciated. Thanks a lot.

PS: I am new to Callbacj functions, Win32 API programming.

Comment: You have a multitude of messages you can be sent. One for normal windows is `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, sent when the user presses the left mouse button down on your window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [window message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx) or more precisely a dialog message in this case. The analogous parameter exists also in [normal window procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573.aspx).

There are various types of window messages, many of them starting with `WM_` or another distinct prefix depending on the window class (class is not meant in the OOP sense here, but rather in the Win32 sense).

The message says what kind of "operation" is taking place (from the point of view of the window/dialog) or which you want to induce (view from the outside). The parameters `lParam` and `wParam` then allow to give more information concerning that "operation".

Some messages are merely notifications, others can be sent to windows to induce some operation.

Comment: Thank you. So I just wanted to clarify if my understanding is correct or not.   So when I use a callback function while creating a dialog box; say the dialog box has some controls like a slider bar. So, when I left click on slider bar, windows would call this callback function with appropriate Windows message and also the appropriate lParam and wParam. Am I right ? .

Comment: @codeLover: yes. The most likely message to handle events for the child windows (i.e. those controls) would be `WM_COMMAND` and a few others.